# Azure Functions sync from remote to local

Tags: azure, azure-functions

My hard disc has crashed. Azure functions were written using Visual Studio Code and deployed to the Azure Functions.

However, right now although I can see all the codes but, I am unable to sync it to my new system in Visual Studio Code.

I am using Consumption Plan, Python in Linux OS.

"Download App Content" is disabled in my account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **`Download App Content`** option is disabled for the Azure Functions Python Linux OS in the Azure Portal.
To download its App Content, you can use the FTP Login like:

1. Go to the deployment Center > Select FTPS Credentials > Copy FTPS Endpoint, Username and Password to the [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) Client > You have the Download option to download all the content.

[image]

- This is possible when you created the Functions using the Azure Portal (Consumption Function App).
- You cannot see the Code files in FTPS Client if you have deployed the Functions from local IDE (VS Code, etc) to the Azure Function App Consumption Plan.
- If you have deployed the functions from local IDE to the Portal Function App (**App Service Plan & Premium Plan**), then you can see the files using FTP Client (eg, WinSCP) using the above method.

Note: You can also get the FTPS endpoint and credentials from the **`Get Publish Profile`** option.
[image]

#### Updated Answer:

If you have deployed the functions from local IDE to Portal Function App (Consumption Mode), then the workaround is to copy the code manually from the portal function app to your local project:

[image]

As of now, I believe the above is the workaround in that scenario. It is not so easy to do manually if many functions (triggers) are present in the Function App, so I would recommend you raise the feature request in the [Azure Functions Python GitHub Repository](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/new?title=&body=%0A%0A%5BEnter%20feedback%20here%5D%0A%0A%0A---%0A%23%23%23%23%20Document%20Details%0A%0A%E2%9A%A0%20*Do%20not%20edit%20this%20section.%20It%20is%20required%20for%20learn.microsoft.com%20%E2%9E%9F%20GitHub%20issue%20linking.*%0A%0A*%20ID%3A%20542c2bdc-5868-71d5-1d1a-a2c6d61744b0%0A*%20Version%20Independent%20ID%3A%201bba15a0-227a-8137-a023-90b8df19881b%0A*%20Content%3A%20%5BCreate%20a%20Python%20function%20using%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%20-%20Azure%20Functions%5D(https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fazure-functions%2Fcreate-first-function-vs-code-python)%0A*%20Content%20Source%3A%20%5Barticles%2Fazure-functions%2Fcreate-first-function-vs-code-python.md%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FMicrosoftDocs%2Fazure-docs%2Fblob%2Fmain%2Farticles%2Fazure-functions%2Fcreate-first-function-vs-code-python.md)%0A*%20Service%3A%20**azure-functions**%0A*%20GitHub%20Login%3A%20%40ggailey777%0A*%20Microsoft%20Alias%3A%20**glenga**).

Comment: Hi, your post is informative. But, I am not sure, it will solve my problem. Will I ever be able to download the files in my new system ? Because, I am using Consumption Plan, and, using FTP I am not able to see much.

Comment: In this case, the workaround is to copy the code manually from the Azure Portal > Function App > Function > copy code from every file like host.json, function.json, init.py etc to your local project!

Comment: @RupakBanerjee, As of now, I believe the above is the workaround in that scenario. It is not so easy to do manually if many functions (triggers) are present in the Function App, so I would recommend you raise the feature request in the Azure Functions Python GitHub Repository.

Comment: I completely agree with you . Thanks for the clarification.